# Sales tax and tip calculator

Tags: javascript, function

Hello I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code I input $10.00 for the bill and 7 for the sales tax, and 25 for the tip. the answer should be 13.38 but for some reason i get 12.59. I am not sure where the coding went wrong?

```
function applyTax(){ 


  var inputAmount = document.getElementById( 'dollars' ).value; 
  var salesTax = document.getElementById( 'tax' ).value;
  var tip = document.getElementById( 'tip' ).value; 
  var totalAmount = (inputAmount*1) + (salesTax * 0.01);
  var tipprcnt = (tip*0.01)*totalAmount;
  var Grandtotal = ((totalAmount*1) + (tipprcnt*1)).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById( 'requestedGrand' ).innerHTML = Grandtotal; 
}
```

Comment: `10 + 7 * 0.01 + (25 * 0.01 * (10 + 7 * 0.01)) = 12.59` is what you are computing. If you don't want that result, then you are using the wrong formula. Seems like your are using the wrong formula for the result you want to get. This is a math problem, not a programming problem. You basically implemented the wrong formula.

Comment: Yea I understand that, Im not too sure how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're assuming you should pay *tax* on a tip, which wouldn't normally be the case.

If you're tipping $2.50 on a $10 bill, you'd pay $12.50.  Adding a 7% tax on that would give you $13.38, which is incorrect.

What you *probably* want to be doing is taxing the $10, and adding a $2.50 tip to that.

```
Sub-Total: $10
Tax: $0.70 (7%)    
Tip: $2.50 (25% of Sub-Total)
```

Or, in JavaScript:

```
var inputAmount = 10;
var tip = 0.25;
var salesTax = 0.07;
var totalAmount = inputAmount +
   (inputAmount * tip) +     // Add on the tip
   (inputAmount * salesTax); // Add on the tax
```

Comment: I tried it this way and somehow I ended up with a bizzarre number like 102.50.7000000000000001

Comment: The point is that I would take in three different inputs then I would calculate all three into 1 grand total I am not sure why it is not correctly working.

Comment: @JasonHuang: Again, because you are using the wrong formula. Which formula do you want to use that produces 13.38 from the values 10, 7, and 25 ?